# TypeError: "'ADGroup'" object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-python-sdk

1. what is ADGroup type
2. after creating the AD group in azure using python sdk how to fetch the object_id or store that in a list
3. im trying to create multiple groups using azure python sdk, passing the group name in json format, i would like to obtain the output and store the info in a json but it throw the error which i have stated in the Title

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac.models import GroupCreateParameters
import json

jsonfile = open('csvjson.json')
data = json.load(jsonfile)

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
client_id = "",
secret = "",
tenant = "",
resource = 'https://graph.windows.net')

tenant_id = ""

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)
groupdict = []
for i in data:
    group = graphrbac_client.groups.create(GroupCreateParameters(display_name=i['Group Name'], mail_nickname=i['Mail Nick Name']), raw=False)
    print(type(group))
```

Comment: Could you include the code you are currently using to create groups?

Comment: Yes I have edited